# Limit Translation parameters for "generic spring" rigid body constraint don't work as expected

Tags: animation, physics, constraints, rigidbody

I have a chain of rigid bodies connected in series by empties with the "generic spring" rigid body constraint like this:

[image: loop]

If the space between the rigid bodies is stretched, the armature which copies the rotations of the rigid bodies cannot correctly follow the chain.

the armature:

[image: armature]

the armature misaligned during animation due to the connections between the rigid bodies being stretched:

[image: armature misaligned]

I've set the translation limits of these springs to 0 because I don't want my rigid bodies being pulled away from each other to any extent and yet this behavior persists.

[image: constraint window]

So how do I keep the rigid bodies in this chain from being pulled from each other if there is a way?

ty.

Comment: A file would go a long way.  Constraints aren't perfect-- high velocities and collisions will override them.  But, there are a lot of other ways for physics to go wrong too.  And, there's a way to make your bones follow your objects even if they do have gaps.

Comment: Hi DED, first of all it would be great if you tell us in very easy sentences what your goal is, because i don't get it what you want to achieve. 2nd: a blend file would be very helpful, because rigid bodies with armatures involved are pretty complex and just one screenshots with a "some" technical infos won't help much.

Comment: still after reading your questions 3 times, i am not sure what you want to achieve? do you want no stretching? if yes, why don't you use point connections instead of springs? why are you using springs at all? ...so please edit your questions to make it crystal clear what you want (i don't mean a technical question, but the "end" result) e.g. i wanna have a necklace animated like in real world.

Comment: @Chris yes, I want no stretching since I suspect that would resolve the misalignment. but I also want the chain to "bounce/spring back" to it's original shape, do point connections allow for that? I also don't know what you mean by "point connections".

I'll edit the question later.

Comment: Basically I wanted to start from scratch, looking at different methods of achieving this rigid body chain, and in doing so have found that the potential cause of this issue is much stranger than expected due to not being repeatable across different .blend files: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310318/blender-physics-and-constraints-not-working-properly-in-a-particular-blend-file
This stretching behavior shouldn't happen to this extent at all.