# Blender physics and constraints not working properly in a particular blend file

Tags: physics, blend-files

For some strange reason the same physics chain setup within a new .blend project works fine, but in my old blender project that I created 2 years ago the constraints do not work properly.

Here is an example of the *exact* same setup pasted into both files...

In the new project (expected behaviour):

[image: new project]

In the old project:

[image]

I speculate that some setting somewhere is messing with my physics globally or my blend file is corrupt in some way that affects blender's capacity to run its physics functionality.

What is the cause of this issue?

problem file:
[image]

Comment: Without the blend files this is a puzzle game.

Comment: @tetii okay I added it, and you can just copy and paste the contents of the blend file to a new project to see how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opening your file in 4.1 it looked like your 2nd image. if i set substeps back to 10 it looked like your first.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware that these settings existed, thank you.

Also, If the physics simulation speed is 1.0,  the sub steps per frame can be left at 1 to resolve this problem.

The speed parameter was set to 4 in my problem file (which I didn't want) so I set it back to 1.